# Suggestions for spell checking HTML with Aptana plugin for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, spell-checking, aptana

I'm using the Aptana plugin for Eclipse to do web development.  Apparently spell checking is disabled in Aptana for performance reasons (see https://aptanastudio.tenderapp.com/discussions/questions/140-invoking-the-version-20-spell-checker).

Currently I drop to a shell and run a script that in turn runs aspell on all my *.html files, but occasionally I forget to do this before I publish.  I've tried adding my script as an "external tools" command, but aspell doesn't behave nicely in an Eclipse console window.  Besides, I still might forget to click it before a publish.

Ideally, I'd like to insert some sort of hook that would run this script before I trigger a file synchronize command, but I would appreciate any other suggestions to trigger an automatic spell check process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach has been to publish using the command line only, that way I can sneak my spell check command in every time before I publish.  I installed an "Open in Terminal" plugin for eclipse that makes it convenient to drop to a shell at the root of the web directory then execute this command.

I hope this is helpful to somebody.

Answer (score 0):

use a separate spell checker

I'm using tinyspell and aptana studio 3 (it can check spellings as you type)

see this http://tinyspell.numerit.com/